# independent component analysis (ICA) algorithms: invention or discovery?

Tags: computational-process, mathematical-algorithm, mathematical-computations, independent-component-analysis, fastica

1) Under the current patent laws (US/EU/wherever) are new ICA algorithms the discovery of mathematical truths or the invention of new procedures to identify independent components of a mixed signal set?

2) Would patenting something in a saturated market be economical anyway?

3) If JADE or a FastICA variant were conceived/discovered today, could it be patented?

This is a more specific variation on :
[Are algorithm-based inventions patentable?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/13804/are-algorithm-based-inventions-patentable)
- In which the answer is given is a general  - Abstract algorithms can't be patented, but applications can be.

How abstract is too abstract?

Comment: You probably already know the Justice Thomas quote from Alice "We need not labor to delimit the precise contours of the 'abstract ideas' category in this case,"

Comment: Ultramerical (Ultramerical v. WildTangent) argued that the abstract idea exception is limited to well-known, fundamental, or routine concepts (http://www.patentdocs.org/2015/06/ultramercial-v-wildtangent-petition-for-writ-of-certiorari.html).  Ultramerical's patent being ruled valid twice before being ruled invalid show this is pretty murky territory.